# How to bind Json response to table

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have `products.components.ts` class, where I am getting `Json` data in `this.Getdata`

```
ngOnInit() {
this._service.getProducts(this.baseUrl)
.subscribe(data => {
  this.Getdata=data
  this.products=data
  alert(JSON.stringify(this.Getdata));      
});
```

This `Josn` data I want to bind in `products.components.html` class `Table`

```
<p>
Product List
</p>
<table>
<th>Id</th> <th>Name</th> <th> Country</th> <th>Actions</th>
<tr *ngFor="let lst of products; let i = index" border="1">
  <td>{{i+1}}</td><td>{{lst.id}}</td><td>{{lst.employee_name}}</td> <td>Edit</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The above code is not working. Only alert displaying. How can I bind data to table?

This is my Json data

```
[{"id":"1","employee_name":"amit","employee_salary":"0","employee_age":"0","profile_image":""},{"id":"247793","employee_name":"Ana","employee_salary":"123","employee_age":"123","profile_image":""},{"id":"247856","employee_name":"Joseph Beltran","employee_salary":"1000","employee_age":"23","profile_image":""},{"id":"247982","employee_name":"testyeyyeye1","employee_salary":"123","employee_age":"23","profile_image":""},{"id":"248007","employee_name":"test100","employee_salary":"123","employee_age":"23","profile_image":""},{"id":"248038","employee_name":"Hendry","employee_salary":"61888","employee_age":"26","profile_image":""}]
```

Model class

```
export class Productlist {
id: string;
employee_name: string;
employee_salary: string;
employee_age: string;
profile_image: string;
}
```

Comment: Your JSON data?

Comment: what was the error ? whether it display the alert ?

Comment: @SivaRmK - Yes alert dispaying with json data

Comment: @Kenny - Please check my updated question

Comment: What do you actually mean by not working? Whether it is showing blank screen or it is not showing table only? or it is showing any error in console?

Comment: Showing only column name in bold and table empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it this way

```
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
public Getdata;
products:Productlist[];

constructor(private employeeService: ProductService) {}

ngOnInit() {
this.employeeService.getProducts(this.baseUrl)
.subscribe((data:any) => {
 this.products=data;
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of subscribing to the `Observable`, consider storing it in a property and then unwrapping it in the template using the `async` pipe.

If you consider that, then you can significantly reduce your Component to this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { EmployeeService } from './employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  employees$: Observable<Array<any>> = this.employeeService.getEmployees();
  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) {}
}
```

And in your Template:

```
<p>
    Employee List
</p>
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th> Country</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees$ | async; let i = index">
            <td>{{i+1}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.employee_name}}</td>
            <td>Edit</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample Demo Code**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-employee-list-from-rest-api?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

**PS:** Consider naming your properties and methods appropriately. If you're working with employees, then it doesn't really make sense to name properties and methods as `products`.

Comment: Iam getting this error  ERROR in _src/app/products/products.component.ts(22,32): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Object' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'._ in first line of `AppComponent`

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya, that's a totally unrelated error and I'd need the whole code from your `products.component.ts` to figure out what's wrong. Plus the error says that the issue is on line 22 of the file. So you might want to navigate to it and see what's wrong there. You seem to have assigned an Object to a string as the error message mentions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

> const myobject= JSON.parse(yourjsonvalue);

You will get the object in myobject and now you can loop through with simple ngFor.